# Multi-Threading in Perl vs Java

Tags: java, multithreading, perl

I am new to Perl and I am writing a program that requires the use of threading. I have found the [threads feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) in Perl, but I find that I am still a bit confused.  As stated in the title of this post Java is probably the most common to use threads.  I am not saying that it is perfect, but I can get the job done using the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class.

In Java I have a method called startThreads and in that method I created the threads and then started them.  After starting them there is a while loop that is checking if the treads are done.  If all the threads have exited properly then the while loop exits, but if not then the while loop is watching what threads have timed out and then safely interrupts those threads and sets their shutdown flags to true.

The problem:
In Perl I want to use the same algorithm that I have stated above, but of course there are differences in Perl and I am new to Perl. Is it possible to have the while loop running while the other threads are running? How is it done?

Comment: Yes it's possible, and it's done in exactly the same way. What have you tried? Just give it a shot, the concepts are the same.

Comment: Have you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html?

Comment: You will be looking probably into the `detach` method, problem there is that you are not able to return anything. Sometimes perl threads can be a little tricky; if you want I can dig up a multi-threaded dns lookup script that I wrote a while back.

Comment: What have you already written (in your Perl code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the link that Michael Slade provided,  I found that Cyber-Guard Enterprise was correct.  By detaching the thread the main still is performing work.  I haven't tested it out yet, but it looks like $thr->is_running() can tell me if the thread is still running.

This was taken from the url that was provided and shows how detach is used.
perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html?

```
use threads;
my $thr = threads->create(\&sub1); # Spawn the thread
$thr->detach(); # Now we officially don't care any more
sleep(15); # Let thread run for awhile
sub sub1 {
$a = 0;
while (1) {
$a++;
print("\$a is $a\n");
sleep(1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your `while` loop in Perl using `threads->list()` but you should consider a different approach, first.

Instead of waiting for threads, how about waiting for results?

The basic idea here is that you have code which takes work units from a queue and which puts the results of the work units (either objects or exceptions) into a output queue.

Start a couple of threads that wait for work units in the input queue. when one show up, run the work unit and put the result in the output queue.

In your main code, you just need to put all the N work units into the input queue (make sure it's large enough). After that, you can wait for N outputs in the output queue and you're done without needing to worry about threads, joins and exceptions.

**[EDIT]** All your questions should be answered in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html

Comment: Aaron, the reason why I am waiting for threads is because they currently don't return any data of any form. Instead they are carrying out tasks.  When a thread finishes it means the task is completed. Sometimes a tasks will take too long and that is why I am watching the threads.  If a task has timed out then I need to safely tell the thread to exit now.  If it still doesn't exit safely then I need to kill the thread.  This leads into my next question about threads and Perl.  Where is a go source on Perl Interrupts, stopping, killing threads...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using threads in perl.  There are a lot of nuances about safely accessing shared data.  Because most Perl code does not do threading, very few modules are thread-safe.